# What's wrong with my selection sort algorithm?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

The answer might be obvious to the trained eye, but I've been hitting the books for a few hours now, my eyes are straining, and I can't seem to see the bug.

Below are two implementations of selection sort I wrote, and neither is sorting the input correctly. You can [play with this code](https://repl.it/CDhD/1) on an online interpreter.

```
def selection_sort_enum(array)
  n = array.length - 1

  0.upto(n - 1) do |i|
    smallest = i

    (i + 1).upto(n) do |j|
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[i]
    end

    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
  end
end

def selection_sort_loop(array)
  n = array.length - 1
  i = 0
  while i <= n - 1
    smallest = i
    j = i + 1
    while j <= n
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[i]
      j += 1
    end
    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Here's the test of the first implementation, `selection_sort_enum`:

```
puts "Using enum:"
a1 = [*1..10].shuffle
puts "Before sort: #{a1.inspect}"
selection_sort_enum(a1)
puts "After sort: #{a1.inspect}"
```

Here's the test of the second implementation, `selection_sort_loop`:

```
puts "Using while:"
a2 = [*1..10].shuffle
puts "Before sort: #{a2.inspect}"
selection_sort_enum(a2)
puts "After sort: #{a2.inspect}"
```

Here's the output of the first implementation, `selection_sort_enum`:

```
Using enum:
Before sort: [7, 5, 2, 10, 6, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9]
After sort:  [4, 3, 1, 9, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 10]
```

Here's the output of the second implementation, `selection_sort_loop`:

```
Using while:
Before sort: [1, 10, 5, 3, 7, 4, 8, 9, 6, 2]
After sort:  [1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: Your question is confusing as written: You have two outputs. It looks like you mean your "first output" to be the code to call the methods. Adjust your question so that's clear please.

Comment: @theTinMan Got it. I've updated it to make it clearer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your first method is perhaps better named `selection_sort_enum!` since you are mutating the original array. To create a new sorted array just change the first line to `def selection_sort_enum(arr); array = arr.dup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both the `code snippets` you are comparing with index `i` instead of index `smallest`.

This should work :

```
def selection_sort_enum(array)
  n = array.length - 1

  0.upto(n - 1) do |i|
    smallest = i

    (i + 1).upto(n) do |j|
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[smallest]
    end
    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
  end
end

def selection_sort_loop(array)
  n = array.length - 1
  i = 0
  while i <= n - 1
    smallest = i
    j = i + 1
    while j <= n
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[smallest]
      j += 1
    end
    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
    i += 1
  end
end
```

Output :

```
Using enum:
Before sort: [5, 6, 7, 9, 2, 4, 8, 1, 10, 3]
After sort: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Using while:
Before sort: [6, 5, 9, 2, 1, 3, 10, 4, 7, 8]
After sort: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Link to solution : http://ideone.com/pKLriY

Comment: They both work for me. Mohamad, even though `array` is changed in place, you may want to return by making `array` the last line.

Comment: Thank you. @CarySwoveland so it turned out to be something subtle. Oh dear, my attention to detail needs work. The book even states it as `A[smallest]` instead of `A[i]`... live in learn. Thank you both.

Comment: As a Ruby-way thing, it's better to name a modifying method using a trailing `!` to denote that the method is modifying, not returning a copy or new object.

Comment: @theTinMan indeed! So either return a copy or change the method name to `selection_sort!`... on a side note, I'm really sad I lost an hour and a half trying to figure this out. I can be my own worst enemy sometimes.

Comment: It's hard to say whether an hour and a half of frustration is truly lost time. (Old Japanese proverb or something I just made up to sound like such.)

Answer (score 1):

```
def selection_sort_enum(array)
  n = array.length - 1 

  0.upto(n) do |i| # n instead of (n - 1)
    smallest_index = i

    (i + 1).upto(n) do |j|
      smallest_index = j if array[j] < array[i]
    end

    puts "#{array}", smallest_index
    array[i], array[smallest_index] = array[smallest_index], array[i] if i != smallest_index
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me, but some explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this:

```
def selection_sort_enum(array)
  n = array.length - 1

  0.upto(n - 1) do |i|
    smallest = i

    (i + 1).upto(n) do |j|
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[i]
    end

    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
  end
  array # <-- added to return the modified array
end

def selection_sort_loop(array)
  n = array.length - 1
  i = 0
  while i <= n - 1
    smallest = i
    j = i + 1
    while j <= n
      smallest = j if array[j] < array[i]
      j += 1
    end
    array[i], array[smallest] = array[smallest], array[i] if i != smallest
    i += 1
  end
  array # <-- added to return the modified array
end

require 'fruity'

ARY = (1 .. 100).to_a.shuffle
compare do
  _enum { selection_sort_enum(ARY.dup) }
  _loop { selection_sort_loop(ARY.dup) }
end
```

Which results in:

```
# >> Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> _enum is faster than _loop by 3x ± 1.0
```

Comment: I'm really surprised that enum is faster than looping. I thought that a loop, being a primitive operation, would be faster. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't edit code in answers. While this answer is only informative, it's also a record of the test performed. Changing the code is a change to the intended meaning of a question or answer and is not done. That the code returned an incorrect result isn't the point, it's that one was significantly faster than the other. You're welcome to ask for changes.